# How to Execute assembly language code in CMD Windows XP?

Tags: windows, assembly

I have learned assembly language coding. Now I want to check it by running on Windows XP command prompt.

I have entered debug command and wrote assembly language code successfully.
the problem I am getting is how to execute the commands I have written on it?

Any key,  statement or else?

Please help me in this case. I have my exam on Sunday.
Regards.

Comment: Use Microsoft Macro Assembler 8.0 (MASM) Package

Comment: inside debug, you can call "g = 100" to start a program (in this example starting at address 0x100). this will run 'til you hit a "INT 3" breakpoint. You can also set the PC (via "r PC") to point to the address where you want to run, and then trace through the code step-by-step via "n"

Comment: btw: writing ? will make debug showing his help

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to put the asm instructions in a file and assemble them with a normal assembler, instead of generating your program inside the debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to show how to redirect some assembler mnemonics and debug commands for to telecontrol debug within a batchfile and some pipe(> <) operators. Description: The first step is to redirect all commands + assembler instructions into a temporary textfile and the second step is to redirect the temporary textfile to debug.

This following example have to be copy and paste into a new texttfile. And the textfile have to be renamed with the "bat" file-extension: Example: "Hello.bat"

```
@echo off
echo a cs:100>tmp.deb
echo mov dx,108>>tmp.deb
echo mov ah,9>>tmp.deb
echo int 21>>tmp.deb
echo ret>>tmp.deb
echo db "Hello World!$">>tmp.deb
echo g=cs:100 107>>tmp.deb
echo q>>tmp.deb
debug<tmp.deb>tmp.inf
del tmp.deb
type tmp.inf
```

Debug manual: http://www.armory.com/~rstevew/Public/Tutor/Debug/debug-manual.html